# Ensemble mean of a fraction

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance

I want to compute the ensemble mean of the term: $\frac{Y^2}{X}$
Both $X$ and $Y$ are random variables that are not independent. I want to compute $E[\frac{Y^2}{X}]$. I proceed as follows, (Using the formula for splitting a RV into mean and fluctuation $A=E[A]+A'$)

$\frac{Y^2}{X}=\frac{(E[Y]+Y')^2}{E[X]+X'}=\frac{\left((E[Y])^2+Y'^2+2E[Y]Y'\right)}{E[X]\left(1+\frac{X'}{E[X]}\right)}$

$~~~~~=\frac{1}{E[X]}\left((E[Y])^2+Y'^2+2E[Y]Y'\right)*\left(1-\frac{X'}{E[X]}\right)$

Using Taylor series expansion upto linear order. This means the above relation is true for $|\frac{X'}{E[X]}|<<1$

This implies

$\frac{Y^2}{X}=\frac{1}{E[X]}\left[(E[Y])^2-\frac{(E[Y])^2}{E[X]}X'+Y'^2-\frac{1}{E[X]}X'Y'^2+2E[Y]Y'-\frac{2E[Y]}{E[X]}Y'X' \right]$

$E[\frac{Y^2}{X}]=\frac{1}{E[X]}\left[(E[Y])^2-\frac{(E[Y])^2}{E[X]}E[X']+E[Y'^2]-\frac{1}{E[X]}E[X'Y'^2]+2E[Y]E[Y']-\frac{2E[Y]}{E[X]}E[Y'X'] \right]$

also noting that $E[A']=0$, the above leads to

$E[\frac{Y^2}{X}]=\frac{1}{E[X]}\left[(E[Y])^2+E[Y'^2]-\frac{1}{E[X]}E[X'Y'^2]-\frac{2E[Y]}{E[X]}E[Y'X'] \right]$

Is there a way to get rid of $E[..]$ terms on the R.H.S? I don't have the distributions corresponding to $Y$ and $X$, but there is a complicated equation relating these two variables. Also, $X$ and $Y$ have a negative covariance relationship.

Comment: Could you add some simulation results for a histogram Y^2/X where you indicate the sample mean of this and the analytical expression? Just out of curiosity to see the agreement in an explicit situation

Comment: @Ggjj11 Thanks. I don't have any simulation results or histogram, however I do have the equation relating these variables: $Y=ae^{\alpha t}/(1+ae^{\alpha t}\int\limits_0^tXe^{a\tau}d\tau)$.

Comment: Because there is no general formula, please state the problem *you actually have* rather than some abstract generalization of it.

Comment: @whuber It is actually a term inside the logistic growth model: $dY/dt=\mu Y\left(1-Y/X \right)$. I am trying to find the mean of the term $Y^2/X$ inside it. However, I do not have a particular distribution of $Y$ and $X$.

Comment: And that's exactly the problem: to get beyond the definition you *need* a particular distribution for $(X,Y).$

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your clarification. Would it be possible if I have a distribution, for one of the two variables? For example, if its Weibull for $X$? There is already a relationship between the two, via the equation. Though its a bit complicated.

Comment: It's hard to tell, because your expression for $Y$ suggests $X$ is not a random variable, but rather a stochastic process.  Otherwise, you would just factor it out of the integral.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your enlightening comment, till now I was confused between the two, i.e., whether it is R.V or a stochastic process. So essentially you meant that if it is a R.V. it could be factored out of the integral because its domain is the sample space, and not the integration measure $\tau$ i.e., $\int\limits_a^b X(w)d\tau=X(w)[a-b]$? Only in this case it would be possible to attach a distribution to it? If say it is a R.V., as it is a carrying capacity and we attach a Weibull distribution to it, will that make it possible?